# what is the Transformation matrix for the linear transformation $T:M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given $A_{1}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 2\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right),A_{2}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & -2\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$ , as $W=sp\{A_{1},A_{2}\}$

Let $T:M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ be a linear transformation defines as:
$T(A_1)=A_2, \ T(A_2)=-A_1$. $\ker T=W^{\perp}$.

Find an Orthonormal base for $W^{\perp}$ and determine whether $T$ is a normal transformation.

***My Attempt:***

what I did what to treat $A_1, A_2$ as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, hence $A_1 = \frac{1}{3}(2, 2,1,0), A_2 = \frac{1}{3} (2, -2,0,1)$.

$A_1$ and $A_2$ are linear independent, therefore $\dim W =2$ and $dim (KerT)= dim (W^{\perp}) =  2$, which also means that $dim(ImT) =2$.

I solved the system $\left(\begin{array}{c}
A_{1}\\
A_{2}
\end{array}\right)x=0,\ x=(x,y,z,w) $ to find $W^{\perp}$, hence $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
2 & -2 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$  , and $W^{\perp}= sp \{(-1,-1,4,0),(-1,1,0,4)\}$.

**Now**, I'd would like to use the transformation matrix in order to determine whether $T$ is normal.

Let the transformation matrix be called $[T]$. it needs to be a $4\times 4$ matrix, and $rank([T])=2$.

is that the correct matrix: $[T]=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & 1 & 0\\
-\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & 0 & 1\\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$, I think this is the transformation matrix because if we choose a base to $\mathbb{R}^4$ constructed by $B={A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4)$ as $\{A_3,A_4}$ are the vectors\matrix which composes the base for $KerT$, then this each column vector describes the image of T over the vectors belongs to the base $B$.

From that, I conclude that $T$ is a normal transformation, because $[T][T]^t=[T]^{t}[T]$.